# How to list records of a Table with a counter of how many are used through a relationship

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, postgresql-9.1, rails-postgresql

I have these 2 tables:

```
create_table "instruments", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    ...

  create_table "user_instruments", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "instrument_id"
    ...
```

With these relationships:

```
class Instrument < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :user_instruments
  has_many :users, :through => :user_instruments

class UserInstrument < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :instrument
```

How to query all the instruments, with a counter of how many times it is being used, like:

**Instrument.select('name,User_instrument.group(:instrument_id).count').all**

or maybe:

**UserInstrument.includes(:instruments).group('instrument_id as count').select('instrument.name, count')**

This works at the view level but it creates too many queries:

```
<% @instruments.each_with_index do |instrument,idx| %>
      ...
    <td><%= instrument.users.count %></td>
      ...
<%end%>
```

How to do that with 1 query?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to just show count then you can use `to_a` method to convert it to array and then call count method on it.

```
# Controller
@instruments = Instrument.all.eager_load(:users)

# View
<% @instruments.each do |instrument| %>
  <td><%= instrument.users.to_a.count %></td>
<% end %>
```